# wallpaper service in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

i want some information about iPhone api. basically i'm a android developer .now i want to port my android application to iPhone. my application is live wallpaper. is there any way to apply live wallpaper service in iPhone.if possible means?
1.how to get touch event in home screen.
2.what are api i need to fallow in iPhone.can i able to use any of the iPhone background service for that.`(wallpaper service)`
3.if i done like this app store will accept my app?. 
guide me thank you.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save images to Library and give instructions to user on how to set it as wallpaper. You cannot set a wallpaper programmatically. Your app will probably be rejected if you use any methods from private API.